# How can I detect fullscreen change or exit with DXGI and SetFullScreenState(...) with Directx10?

Tags: directx, fullscreen, dxgi

I didn't found the solution of the problem described below for days :

So, I need to know how to get the moment when my directx application has finished going fullscreen or windowed mode, especially when it has totally completed the process.

I read that I can use `DXGI_STATUS_MODE_CHANGED` or `DXGI_STATUS_MODE_CHANGE_IN_PROGRESS` return values, but I don't know which function I could use to get these values !

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/dxgi-status

(Thanks for you help)

For example, I used `IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState(true, nullptr)`

It works and the application goes fullscreen, but I don't know how to get the moment when the rendering goes back (the moment when I can see my rendering back)

Comment: Please edit your code so it becomes readable.

Comment: What do you mean by "the moment when the rendering goes back"? Typically it should not be interrupted.